# Filter array of objects based on multiple properties/conditions

Tags: sharepoint-online, filter, duplicate

I have 5 items in a list that is being retrieved and stored in an array using RestAPI.

The end goal here is to filter the array of objects based on 4 conditions(4 columns). 2 List items have the exact same values in the columns and I want to store these 2 items in a separate array as duplicates(Matching Values).

**Code**

```
getResp = data.d.results; // response array
var FltrInv = [];

const lookup = getResp.reduce((a, e) => {
  a[`${e.PCF_x0020_No}_${e.Item_x0020_No}_${e.Material}_${e.YourReference}`] = ++a[`${e.PCF_x0020_No}_${e.Item_x0020_No}_${e.Material}_${e.YourReference}`] || 0;
  return a;
}, {});

FltrInv = getResp.filter(e => lookup[e.PCF_x0020_No]);
```

This code returns an empty array as highlighted below.

[image]

Tried all the solutions on this link , However none of them worked for my scenario.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53212020/get-list-of-duplicate-objects-in-an-array-of-objects

Would be extremely grateful if anyone could help me figure this out.

Comment: Did you try to `console.log(lookup)` in between the `reduce` and the `filter` to see what it looks like?  I'm pretty sure your `filter` isn't working because the counter object (your `lookup`) you build in the `reduce` has quite complicated compound keys, and you are only using `e.PCF_x0020_No` as the property accessor, and that object has no properties that are only `e.PCF_x0020_No`.  Try using that same complex string construction that's in the reducer also in the filter.

Comment: @Dylan thank you for replying. I was referring to the link mentioned in my question and the code works fine for a single property , However I've been wrapping my head around how to use it with multiple properties , also I'm not aware how to call the filter with multiple parameters. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Please re-read what I wrote about your code.  I looked at that other question and saw how you modified that answer based on the comments in that other thread.  Again, I think your `filter` is not working because when you build your `lookup` object, you give it long property names like "Field1Value_Field2Value_Field3Value", but when you try to _access_ those properties in the `filter`, you are only looking for `lookup["Field1Value"]`.  You need to set up that same long compound string of "Field1Value_Field2Value_Field3Value" _in your `filter`_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you are not getting any results from your `filter` because when you build your counter object in the reducer, you build it with complex property names that are combining many of your SharePoint field values into one long string, and then when you try to access the properties of the counter object in the filter, you are only specifying *one* of the SharePoint fields to try to find the property.

There are no properties on that object that have only the value of one of the SharePoint fields.

If you were to `console.log(lookup)` right after you build it using the `reduce()` function, you will see an object that looks something like this:

```
{
    "3001317_0001_Wood_FOO": 0,
    "3001317_0001_Metal_BAR": 1,
    "3001316_0002_Wood_FOO": 0,
    "3001316_0002_Metal_FOO": 2,
    "3001316_0001_Wood_BAR": 0
}
```

Now, the way that reducer works is that it adds a new property with that complex property name for each unique combination of those four field values.  When it first adds it, it gives it a value of `0`.  `0` in this case means there is *one* item that has that unique combination of four field values.  Then, if it finds *another* item with the same combination, it increments the counter.  So a counter value of `1` means there are actually two duplicate items, and `2` means there are actually three items that are identical.

The reason the `filter` then works to pull out the duplicates is because you are checking against the counter object, and if there was only one unique item, then the counter value for that combination will be `0`, which is a *falsy* value, so the filter won't pull it, whereas if there were duplicates, the counter value will be `1` (or more), which is a *truthy* value, so the filter *will* pull it.

But, in your filter, you are only using the one field to try to access the counter properties, like this:

```
var askingForValue = lookup["3001317"]
```

BUT - remember all the properties on the counter are much more than just that, there is no property on the counter object that is as simple as `"3001317"`.

So what you have to do is re-create the complex property names / keys you created in the reducer:

```
FltrInv = getResp.filter(e => lookup[`${e.PCF_x0020_No}_${e.Item_x0020_No}_${e.Material}_${e.YourReference}`]);
```

Also keep in mind, that filter will pull all the items that have duplicates, even if there are multiple sets of duplicates.

For example, if you look back at my fictitious counter object, if you ran that `filter` over the SharePoint results, you would end up with an array of 5 items:

- 2 items would have field values 3001317 / 0001 / Metal / BAR
- 3 items would have field values 3001316 / 0002 / Metal / FOO

Comment: Thank you so much Dylan for the detailed explanation. In the response array , there are only two rows where the column values match , the remaining 3 rows do not have matching data based on the column values , hence I want to return only those two rows where the column values are exactly the same and ignore the remaining 3. Can that be achieved?

Comment: Yes, it should work exactly like that - as long as you set up the `filter` function to access the `lookup` counter object using the same complex property names you set up in the `reduce` function.  I put an example of doing exactly that in my answer.

Comment: This is working as expected , Thank you for all the help like always :)
Please accept my connection request on linkedin